# Integral $ \int_{0}^\infty (\cos(4x))^{\sin(x)} \text{ dx} =\mbox{?}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$ \int_{0}^\infty (\cos(4x))^{\sin(x)} \text{ dx} =\mbox{?}$$

I've tried $\frac{\pi}{2} -x = t$ (integration using substitution) but had no progress.

Comment: It's an *improper* integral. What exactly are you expected to do with it? (Also, raising negative numbers to fractional, maybe irrational powers? Come on)

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Find the value...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are at least two ways in which this integral does not make sense:

1. $\cos(4x)$ can be negative on the domain of integration. How are you defining raising these negative numbers to arbitrary real powers? Is there an absolute value missing somewhere?
2. The improper integral of a (nonzero) periodic function $f(x)$ never exists. To see this, notice that **if** the value of the improper integral converged, it must be equal to

   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \,dx$$

and so $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx = 0$. Therefore $\int_0^t f(x)\,dx$ is itself periodic and there is no chance it converges as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: I actually came to the same conclusion you did in (2) in my deleted answer,but I actually took the upper limit at infinity.But even taking the limit and saying it diverges isn't really correct,is it?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you can compute $\int_0^{2\pi} f$ and, if it's not zero, say that the improper integral diverges. But in this case who knows, since even the definite integral isn't defined due to issue #1.